# How to convert json string to array of objects without sorting so that can be used as data for JQgrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

Json string

```
[{"Date":"1","Time":"2007-10-01","Tag":"test","JetSpeed":"note","HeadTemp":"200.00","FaultList":"10.00;"},{"Date":"2","Time":"2007-10-02","Tag":"test2","JetSpeed":"note2","HeadTemp":"300.00","FaultList":"20.00;"},{"Date":"3","Time":"2007-09-01","Tag":"test3","JetSpeed":"note3","HeadTemp":"400.00","FaultList":"30.00;"}]
```

Code

```
var logtabledata = $.parseJSON(data.Parameters)
```

When i use this gives me arrayobjects Example `logtable[0]` will be key is `Date` value is `1` next key is `Faultlist` value is `10.00` .....it arranges the data in sorted order. I need to preserve the order it comes. How to do this? How to preserver the order so that same order can be used for showing in grid data

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: logtabledata
})
```

I need the data in same order after parsing from json

Comment: its already json object you don't need to parse it.

Comment: *"it arranges the data in sorted order"*; no, it doesn't. The order is unchanged

Comment: No sorting is happening. You are confused with your question.

Comment: Sorting is happened after parsing from json but i need the data in same order i passed

Comment: @ sohil,but i use same the json string to jqgrid data data is not displayed so data parameter requires array of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jqgrid documentation I think you need to set [`colModel`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options):

> Array which describes the parameters of the columns.This is the most important part of the grid.

Something like:

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: logtabledata,
    colModel: [
      { name: 'Date' },
      { name: 'Time' },
      { name: 'Tag' },
      { name: 'JetSpeed' },
      { name: 'HeadTemp' },
      { name: 'FaultList' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: ok thanks its working based on colmodel logtabledata is added